# Spring Boot - Scan whole packages without @EntityScan/@EnableJpaRepositories

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

Below is my Spring Boot starter class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example"})
@EntityScan("com.example.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")
public class SpringAppApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringAppApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Now, how can I configure something like `@ComponentScan({"com.example.*"})` 
so that I can avoid adding `@EntityScan("com.example.entity")` and `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")`

Comment: You don't need anything but `@SpringBootApplication` defined. Spring Boot will pick up repositories, enities, and sterotype annotations of beans. The only thing you should do is have this main application in the root package so that it will component scan all the packages without having to define them yourself.

Comment: Spring boot starer is not running and getting failed throwing messages asking to define repositories/entities. I have added the changes as in the mentioned code and error is gone. Application ran fine. After further research on root cause, it was found that above changes are needed when you have different packages for storing entities/repositories. Now please go ahead and re-read my question.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe
I got what you were saying, it has the answer for my above response and the actual question as well! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

`@SpringBootApplication` annotation is actualy 3 annotations in one which includes the `@ComponentScan` (take a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation)). And if you have it in the root package of your project (which is considered a good practice) you do not have to do anything there.

`@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` are different and are related to `spring data` library so it really kinda makes sense NOT to have them included in `@SpringBootApplication`.

Because these annotations could easily be on a configuration class for database or something like that (separating your configuration classes also has it's benefits sometimes).

If you want, you can always write your own custom annotation and inherit the two (or 4) annotations you want. There are plenty of online resources out there on the topic.